# Performing Pywinauto scripts from C# based application is slow

Tags: python, c#, performance

Updated on May 7th, history information is under line "***********************"

@Jakub Sowa  I cannot add any comment below yours, I tried top_window and children(), it didn't seem to work to me. fox example
 tp = cg.appConnect().top_window()
 tp.children(title="finance", control_type="Button").draw_outline()

error occurs like-- AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'draw_outline'

So would you give me a specific example to demonstrate how does it work in your case?

---

I've been doing pywinauto automation for a couple of months, but it runs slowly for some code, for example:

I click the button for confirmation in following code:

```
self.dlg = cg.appConnect().window(title="Hygine_Platform", control_type="Window")

self.regdlg = self.dlg.child_window(title ="registry", auto_id ="FormRegBalance", control_type="Window") 

self.okbtn = self.regdlg.child_window(title="confirm",auto_id="btnOk",control_type="Button")

def clickConfSettle(self):

self.okbtn.click_input()
```

If I use clickConfSettle(), it takes at least five seconds to complete. Does anybody have the same problem, is there any solution for this? I've checked the structure of the controls, it is quite simple, only has 3 levels.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the library for a week or two only, but I've figured that if you get the Window Specification of the top window and it's children as soon as possible like so `self.app.top_window().children()` where `app` is the  `pywinauto.Application(backend='uia', allow_magic_lookup=False).connect(handle=self.handle)` then your application should work much faster.

It takes the dict lookup away from you, however, you can still access items by indexes or iterate over them (which in my case was way faster than using `child_window` method). I'm not sure about the clicking part though as it may require some more time, but for the most part - all of the lookups in my program have gone under 1s after that change.

Comment: yes, the problem may not be caused by clicking, but by finding the element, I am using "uia" too, but if you use children(), it may take much time on scripts maintenance, right? I don't know how to correctly use index, I'll try.

Comment: Well, I haven't really tested my script in production yet, but I think that as long as you name the variables meaningfully, you should be ok. Remember that children() can take parameters like control type, which will reduce the number of returned controls.

Let me know if my solution helps you!

Comment: I cannot add any comment below yours, I tried top_window and children(), it didn't seem to work to me. fox example tp = cg.appConnect().top_window() tp.children(title="finance", control_type="Button").draw_outline()

error occurs like-- AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'draw_outline'
So would you give me a specific example to demonstrate how does it work in your case?

Comment: Well, just as the error description says - the `children` method returns a list of children that match your description, so you'll always have to choose one of them, however you can add more criteria to the `children` arguments to reduce the number of returned elements. There's also an `iter_children` method, which returns a generator (even faster than the first one) and which uses tree walker (the other method sometimes doesn't show elements that are not marked as `is_control=True`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer with what I've tried so far. If I use var.children(attributes), index is still required. so it works with var.children(attributes)[], that runs faster than before.